# Using netﬂixroulette API not working on Xamarin.Forms Based Android APP

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

When i am making call to netflix api ([https://netﬂixroulette.net/api/api.php?actor=Richard](https://net%EF%AC%82ixroulette.net/api/api.php?actor=Richard)) in Xamarin.Forms for Android. it gives error like "Java.Net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "netﬂixroulette.net": No address associated with hostname" but for other api's its working fine.

```
private string url = "https://netﬂixroulette.net/api/api.php?actor=";
        private HttpClient _client = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler());
var content = await _client.GetStringAsync(url + e.NewTextValue);
            var movies = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Movie>>(content);

            lst.ItemsSource = movies;
```

I am using these packages
Microsoft.Bcl.Build, Microsoft.Net.Http, Newtonsoft.Json, modernhttpclient

Comment: Don't need to use ModernHttpClient anymore. You should be able to change the HttpClient handler in the Android and iOS project options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an invalid character (`ﬂ`) in your URL:

Wrong:

```
https://netﬂixroulette.net/api/api.php?actor=Richard
```

Correct:

```
https://netflixroulette.net/api/api.php?actor=Richard
```